# populate array of objects in mongoose

Tags: mongoose, schema, populate

I have 2 schemas. First schema is appointmentSchema.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const patientSchema = require("./patient");

    const appointmentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        patientQueue: [
            {
                patient: patientSchema,
                _id: false,
            },        
        ]
```

2nd schema is patientSchema inside an array patientQueue.

```
const patientSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    userName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    userId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User',
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
  }, {_id: false});
```

I would like to populate the User using the userId. How would I populate it?

```
let appointment = await Appointment.findById(id).populate(???)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.populate("user", "fields-to-populate")
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to replace this part of your code .

```
 const appointmentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    patientQueue: [
        {
            patient: patientSchema,
            _id: false,
        },        
    ]
```

to

```
 const appointmentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    patientQueue: [
        {
            type: String
            ref: 'patientschema'
        },        
    ]
```

Then you could do

```
let appointment = await Appointment.findById(id).populate('patientQueue');
```

There are other ways of doing this.
I will drop the official mongoose doc which has examples that might help.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#deep-populate

I had a schema which had nested arrays of objects which required to populate.

```
    const QuestionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  category: String,
  subCategory: String,
  date: Date,
  title: String,
  description: String,
  user: {
    type: String,
    ref: 'userschema'
  },
  img: String,
  tags: [{type: String}],
  answers: [{
    type: String,
    ref: 'answerschema',
    comments: [{
      type: String,
      ref: 'commentschema'
    }]
  }],
  isOpen: Boolean,
  votes: Number
})
```

And the code which worked for me was

```
const data = await Question.findOne({ _id: id }).populate('user').populate('answers').populate({ path: 'answers', populate: { path: 'comments'} });
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The Document#populate() method does not support chaining. You need to call populate() multiple times, or with an array of paths, to populate multiple paths

```
await person.populate(['stories', 'fans']);
person.populated('fans'); // Array of ObjectIds
```

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate_an_existing_mongoose_document